# How do I setup https with a LetsEncrypt certificate?

Tags: ssl, https, curity

I am trying to setup https on the curity server with letsencrypt certificates. I would like to automate it so that when the certificate expires curity can read and use that  new certificate (possibly without reloading.)

Currently I am unable to get the certificates imported into curity. I have created the `/etc/init/crypto/signer-truststores` and `/etc/init/crypto/ssl-server-truststore` directories and have copied my `cert.pem` into `signer-truststores` and `fullchain.pem` into `ssl-server-truststore` names as `mydomain.com.pem`. As states in https://curity.io/docs/idsvr/latest/system-admin-guide/crypto/index.html?highlight=https add certificates into these locations and curity will auto import them.

Furthermore on the link above it says

> "IMPORTANT: The server needs to be started with the appropriate
> start-up arguments to consider reloading configuration files, please
> for more information please see Server Configuration overview."

I click on the link to Server Configuration and don't see anywhere what to add to get curity to import these certificates.

Can someone tell me where I need to place my certificates (so that I can automatically create a bash script to do it for me when keys expire) and so that curity will import them?

**Edit**: I have tried creating a certificate with privkey.pem and cert.pem. The site is now secured but I still do not know how to import https certificates through localfiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't restart the server to reload the new certificates.

If the script that refreshes the certificates runs on the same machine, you can use the configuration CLI (`idsh`), otherwise the RESTConf API to configure the certificates on the fly. A sample script that can do this is shown below:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

DOMAIN=login.example.com
SERVICE_ROLE=default
PATH=$PATH:$IDSVR_HOME/bin

certbot certonly \
    --agree-tos \
    -d $DOMAIN \
    -n \
    --standalone

XMLFILE=$(mktemp -u /tmp/conf-XXXXXX)
trap "rm -f $XMLFILE" EXIT

KEY=$(cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOMAIN/privkey.pem)
CERT=$(cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOMAIN/cert.pem)

cat <<EOF > $XMLFILE
<config xmlns="http://tail-f.com/ns/config/1.0">
  <facilities xmlns="https://curity.se/ns/conf/base">
    <crypto>
      <ssl>
        <server-keystore>
          <id>letsencrypt-ssl-key</id>
          <keystore>
$KEY
$CERT          
          </keystore>
        </server-keystore>
      </ssl>
    </crypto>
  </facilities>
</config>
EOF

idsh <<< "configure
load merge $XMLFILE
set environments environment services service-role $SERVICE_ROLE ssl-server-keystore letsencrypt-ssl-key
commit"
```

Regarding where to import, I would suggest to use the UI and import a new SSL Server Keystore from a .p12 or a .pem.

Comment: I am fairly new to the CLI, I have looked at the docs and I am assumbing I need to change 

```admin-service{
   http{
       ssl-sever-keystore (certificate name)
```

Since the certificate is being refreshed (as in the values are changing) how do I replace the old (certificate name) certificate with the new certificate of same name?

Comment: I edited Niko's answer with a sample script, @TheRoyalNoob. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

There are in general two types of certificates - the one in truststores and the ones where you have a key that are stored in keystores. During the first startup you can initialize the system with among others trusted (root) certificates (truststores). However, it is not supported to load keystores ("private certificates") in this way. To import a certificate and related key you need to use the UI, CLI or RESTConf API.

There is an extra section in the configuration for certificates and keys, e.g. SSL server certificates (and keys) are placed under `facilities crypto ssl server-keystore`. Each entry in this section has an id. When configuring HTTPS you just refer to the id of the keystore entry, which contains the server certificate that should be used. As a result, replace existing certificates in the `facilities crypto ssl server-keystore` section. As long as the id remains the same there is no need for further updates. In particular, you do not need to change anything in `admin-service http ssl-server-keystore`. The Curity Identity Server will automatically pick up the new certificate from the crypto section.

To import the new certificate using the CLI you can either create a (temporary) config-xml that contains the updated keystore and merge it via the CLI, or use the request command: `idsh <<< "request facilities crypto add-ssl-server-keystore id $certificateName keystore $base64EncodedKeystore password $passwordForKeystore"`.